# Kafka operation on NestJS

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs, reply

Thease days I'm very confusing some kafka performance or setting issues.

Basically consumer server is very well operated. But subscribeToResponseOf(pattern) of NestJS is a function that can response of topic using origin_topic.reply.

The reply is very slow, sometimes is fast but sometimes is very slow if it looks like re-connect to kafka or seeking origin_topic.reply

Have you ever heard this function 's spedd isuue, "this.kafka.subscribeToResponseOf(pattern)"

If I debug this operation, even if consumer server already have operated well done amd then the response time is too late of subscribing reply topic of producer server.

I tried to partition number 1 ~ 6 partition.
If I use 6 partition, it looks a little bit fast in 5 times request. But 6 times request is very slow. I cannot find why the response of reply topic producer server's is very slow even if consumer server is operated well completed.

my source code like this below

```
// This is producer Server 
@Injectable()
export class OrdersController implements OnModuleInit {
  // `constructor`를 사용하여 `UserService` 클래스를 가져와 사용합니다
  // 필수! controller에 service를 주입하기 위해서는 user.module.ts에 controller와 service가 정의되어야 합니다

  constructor(
    private readonly ordersService: OrdersService,
    @Inject('KAFKA_PRODUCER_ORDER') private readonly kafka: ClientKafka // @Inject(MOMENT) moment: Moment, // @Inject(MOMENT_TZ) mtz: MomentTz
  ) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    const requestPatterns = [
      'createOrder',
      'orderListByUserId',
      'orderListByPlaceId',
      'orderListByOrderNo',
      'createOrderLog',
      'updateOrder',
      'findAllByUserId'
    ];
    requestPatterns.forEach((pattern) => {
      this.kafka.subscribeToResponseOf(pattern);
    });
    await this.kafka.connect();
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
     await this.kafka.close();
  }

  @ApiOperation({ summary: '결제정보 등록: pay gateway 와 연동해야 함.' })
  @Post()
  async createOrder(@Body() createOrdersBody: CreateOrdersRequestDto): Promise<CreateOrdersRequestDto | undefined> {
    const pattern = 'createOrder';
    return this.kafka
      .send<CreateOrdersRequestDto>(pattern, JSON.stringify(createOrdersBody))
      .pipe(timeout(5000)) // 5초 timeout setting.
      .toPromise();
  } 


// this is consumer Server
@UseFilters(CustomExceptionFilter)
@Controller()
export class OrdersController {
  constructor(private readonly ordersService: OrdersService, private readonly config: ConfigService) {}

  @MessagePattern('createOrder')
  async create(@Payload(new ValidationPipe()) { value }: { value: KafkaCreateOrderDto }) {
   .......
   ....... Insert or update Database

   console.log(responseMessage);
   return JSON.stringify(responseMessage);

   /* this responseMessage can get on producer server part above using 'createOrder.reply' topic. 
But sometimes it is very slow, 
it takes 2 or 3 seconds even after consumer server operating completed.  */
```

Comment: Are you using actual Kafka or some managed service like Azure Event Hubs or something?

Comment: @Dennis did you get to the bottom of this? I am currently experiencing the same issue. My consumer appears to process the task and send a response in under 300ms, yet my producer takes around 5s to resolve the response.